# Try/Catch method error ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch

I'm trying to make this work. I want it to check if a record exist after inserting but it always return an error: Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'. Can someone point out to me whats wrong in my declaration? Also if you have a better try catch method please enlighten me more. Just new to programming in ASP.NET

Thanks in advance.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connString_LibrarySystem = "Server=DEVSERVER;User ID=sa;Password=Sup3r-Us3r;Database=LibrarySystem";
            string strSQL = "INSERT INTO TblBooks (bookid, booktitle, lastname, firstname, description, categoryid, dateadded, statusid, quantity, isdeleted) VALUES (@bookid, @booktitle, @lastname, @firstname, @description, @categoryid, @dateadded, @statusid, @quantity, @isdeleted)";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString_LibrarySystem);

            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookid", Request.Form["bookid"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@booktitle", Request.Form["booktitle"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", Request.Form["lastname"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", Request.Form["firstname"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", Request.Form["description"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryid", Request.Form["categoryid"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateadded", Request.Form["dateadded"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusid", Request.Form["statusid"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", Request.Form["quantity"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isdeleted", Request.Form["isdeleted"]);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            statuslabel.Text = "Insert successful";
        }
```

EDIT: There just removed the datatypes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to include data type in insert statements. Skip them.

Try

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO TblBooks (bookid, booktitle, lastname, firstname, description, categoryid, dateadded, statusid, quantity, isdeleted) VALUES (@bookid, @booktitle , @lastname, @firstname, @description, @categoryid, @dateadded , @statusid , @quantity, @isdeleted)";
```

Comment: Ok now I have an error: Prepared statement '(@bookid nvarchar(4000),@booktitle nvarchar(4000),@lastname nvar' expects parameter @bookid, which was not supplied. 
Will check if I missed something..

Answer (score 2):

don't put the types in your values.

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO TblBooks (bookid, booktitle, lastname, firstname, description, categoryid, dateadded, statusid, quantity, isdeleted) VALUES (@bookid , @booktitle , @lastname , @firstname , @description , @categoryid , @dateadded , @statusid , @quantity , @isdeleted )";
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to make this work you need to remove the datatypes from the sqlstring variable.

I would probably switch to using a stored procedure and then load parameters since that's basically what you're doing here with the addwithvalue command

also `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will return an int to tell you that it's been added successfully.  if it returns a 1 you know that's it's complete. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Answer (score 2):

At first, remove your types in the SQL, you do not need them (As other answers suggested)

Second, you add a parameter to the query by this :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookid", Request.Form["bookid"]);
```

You do not make sure that Request.Form["bookid"] is not null, this will cause your current problem

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm almost there.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the data types in the values list.  You don't need them.